# Cesium: Is it possible to make the trailing path thinner?

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm using the Cesium library to simulate the satellite motion. This code is used to show the path:

```
path:{
                leadTime:data.data_list[0].period/2,
                trailTime:data.data_list[0].period/2,
                width:1.5,
                material: color
              }
```

Is there a way to make the trailing path thinner?

As an example, the SpaceX video: http://youtu.be/rQEqKZ7CJlk?t=47m40s

Comment: You mean, a thick path at the back of the vehicle, changing to a thin path further away?

Comment: @emackey  The path, which corresponds to the trailTime should be thinner than to leadTime, It would show the path already passed by the satellite. Like in SpaceX video: https://youtu.be/rQEqKZ7CJlk?t=47m40s

Comment: @emackey Probably, there is something to do with the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of comments here.  First, with a width of only 1.5, altering the width is likely not the effect you want.  Try using a solid color vs a faded color, such as by changing the alpha value.  This should be more similar to what you're seeing in that video link.

But, currently Cesium does not support separate path materials for lead and trail times.  If you really need both lead and trail paths shown with different colors/widths/etc, you have to insert a duplicate entity in your CZML (whose position can just be a reference to the primary entity position), such that one entity can have only a leadtime and the other has only a trailtime, and they use different path materials.

But if you have a satellite in a stable orbit, you there's a different approach you can take, because the thing keeps circling around the same path.  You can use the `StripeMaterial` to make the orbit line fade from one side to the other.

[image: Molniya orbit with faded line]

Here's a [live demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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) that loads `simple.czml` and replaces the Molniya's yellow orbit with a faded line.  The solid part is the most recent trail of the satellite, and the faded part is much further back but serves to show where the satellite is headed next.

```
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 5.5;

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    shouldAnimate : true
});

Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load('../../../../Apps/SampleData/simple.czml').then(function(dataSource) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
    viewer.camera.flyHome(0);
    viewer.clock.multiplier = 1800;

    var entity = dataSource.entities.getById('Satellite/Molniya_1-92');

    var fadedLine = new Cesium.StripeMaterialProperty({
        // The newest part of the line is bright yellow.
        evenColor: Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
        // The oldest part of the line is yellow with a low alpha value.
        oddColor: Cesium.Color.YELLOW.withAlpha(0.2),
        repeat: 1,
        offset: 0.25,
        orientation: Cesium.StripeOrientation.VERTICAL
    });

    entity.path.material = fadedLine;
    entity.path.leadTime = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(0);
    entity.path.trailTime = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(3600 * 12);
});
```

Here you can play with the color, of course, but I would recommend keeping the same base color for even and odd.  The `withAlpha` value of `0.2` on the `oddColor` here controls how faded the line gets, range is 0 to 1.  The `offset`value here can also be tweaked, to control the placement of the fade range.  `leadTime` should be zero, and `trailTime` should be the orbit's period.